A question on Gamma function
This might be basic but I have difficulty understanding what exactly goes wrong in the following logic:
Consider the Gammma function
$$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^{\infty} t^{z-1} \, e^{-t}\,dt \quad \textrm{Re}(z) >0.$$
Now let us consider $z=1+iy$ with $y\in \mathbb R$. Then, it seems to me that by triangle inequality there holds:
$$ |\Gamma(1+iy)| \leq \int_0^{\infty} |t^{iy}\,e^{-t}|\,dt \leq 1.$$
However, the previous inequality is obviously in contradiction with Stirling's asymptotic formula for $y$ large. Where is the flaw in this?

$\Gamma$ is fast decreasing on vertical lines so no contradiction

In fact, Stirling's asymptotic
$$
\Gamma(s)\sim s^{s-{1\over 2}}\cdot e^{-s}\cdot (1+O(s^{-1}))
$$
does apply to complex arguments. The hazard is correctly interpreting the $s^s$ that appears, as $s\to\infty$ along vertical lines. Namely, for example,
$$
(1+it)^{1+it} \;=\; e^{(1+it)\log(1+it)}
$$
As $t\to +\infty$, $\log(1+it)$ is essentially ${\pi i\over 2}+\log t$. Thus, the real part of the exponent is essentially $-{\pi\over 2}t + \log t$. Exponentiating gives the vertical exponential decrease...

$\Gamma(1+iy)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{iyx}f(x)dx$ where  $f(x)=\exp (-e^x+x)$ is a nice probability density. So $\Gamma(1+it)\to_{|y |\to \infty}0.$ More explicitely $$|\Gamma(1+iy)|^2=\frac{\pi y}{\sinh y}$$ from the magic formula $\Gamma(p)\Gamma(1-p)=\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi p}.$
